# Mentors IN business vs. Mentors FOR business

Tags: prepositions, for

Which of the following options is correct?

> Mentors **in** business

or

> Mentors **for** business

Comment: _Mentor_ takes _in_ when referring to an area of expertise, and it takes _to_ when referring to the person who is mentored. ... _"Mentor **to** Srta. Martinez **in** business."_ ... ... Welcome to ELL, Linda. I hope you've had time to read our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They will help you to ask good questions!

Comment: But also: "I am looking for a mentor *for* a business seminar." In this case, it has the meaning of a mentor to run the seminar.

Comment: **business mentors" is the term.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to say

> mentors **in** business
>   We are looking for mentors **in** business to teach our marketing students.

means mentors whose expertise is in business.

> mentors **for** business
>   We are looking for mentors **for** our business to help with the product launch.

means mentors who are there to help with business.

Answer (score 0):

In English,  mentors can be found in many areas:

- university mentor [a professor]
- business mentor [a business person who mentors]
- a music mentor
  etc.

You take the area and you make it an adjective.